# Не убирается класс .active

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Что я делаю не так? Хочу убрать класс `.active` при повторном клике, а он заново добавляется.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {


  let accordeon = document.querySelector('.accordeon');
  let accordeon__item = accordeon.querySelectorAll('.accordeon__item');
  let accordeon__item__title = accordeon.querySelectorAll('.accordeon__item__title');
  let accordeon__child__item = accordeon.querySelectorAll('.accordeon__child__item');
  let accordeon__child__item__title = accordeon.querySelectorAll('.accordeon__child__item__title');
  let accordeon__child__group = accordeon.querySelectorAll('.accordeon__child__group');
  let accordeon__grandchild__group = accordeon.querySelectorAll('.accordeon__grandchild__group');

  accordeon__child__item__title.forEach((item, i, array) => {
    item.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
      if (!item.offsetParent.offsetParent.offsetParent.classList.contains('active')) {
        return;
      }
      item.offsetParent.classList.add('active');
    });

    accordeon__grandchild__group[i].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
      item.offsetParent.classList.add('active');
    });

    item.offsetParent.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
      item.offsetParent.classList.remove('active');
    });
  });

  accordeon__item__title.forEach((item, i, array) => {

    let height = accordeon__child__group[i].offsetHeight;
    accordeon__child__group[i].style.height = 0 + 'px';
    item.addEventListener('click', () => { // Клик по меню

      for (let j = 0; j < accordeon__item.length; j++) {
        item.offsetParent.style.transition = 'height 0.3s linear, opacity 0.05s linear';
        accordeon__child__group[j].style.height = 0 + 'px';
        accordeon__child__group[j].style.opacity = '0';
        if (j == i) {
          continue;
        }
        item.offsetParent.classList.remove('active');
      } // Обнуляю все элемы по высоте и прозрачности

      for (let j = 0; j < accordeon__child__item.length; j++) {
        accordeon__child__item[j].style.cursor = 'default';
      } // обнуляю все курсоры

      if (!item.offsetParent.classList.contains('active')) {
        item.offsetParent.style.transition = 'height 0.3s linear, opacity 0.3s linear';
        accordeon__child__group[i].style.height = height + 'px';
        accordeon__child__group[i].style.opacity = '1';
        item.offsetParent.classList.add('active');
      } else {
        item.offsetParent.style.transition = 'height 0.3s linear, opacity 0.05s linear';
        accordeon__child__group[i].style.height = 0 + 'px';
        accordeon__child__group[i].style.opacity = '0';
        item.offsetParent.classList.remove('active');
      }



      for (let j = 0; j < item.nextElementSibling.children.length; j++) {

        if (item.offsetParent.classList.contains('active')) {
          // при клике все элементам .accordeon__child__item задаётся cursor pointer или
          // default, в зависимости от наличия класса active у .accordeon__item
          item.nextElementSibling.children[j].style.cursor = 'pointer';
        } else {
          item.nextElementSibling.children[j].style.cursor = 'default';
        }

      }

    }); // Клик по меню

  });

});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Open+Sans:400,600,700|Raleway:400,900&display=swap');
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.accordeon {
  max-width: 250px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.accordeon__item {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform .5s linear;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.accordeon__item__title {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #3b7ba7;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordeon__item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.accordeon__child__group {
  position: relative;
  transition: height .3s linear, opacity .3s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}

.accordeon__child__item {
  position: relative;
}

.accordeon__child__item__title {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #b1cfe3;
  transition: background-color .2s linear;
}

.accordeon__child__item.active .accordeon__child__item__title {
  background-color: #7fb5d8;
}

.accordeon__grandchild__group {
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform .2s linear;
}

.accordeon__child__item.active .accordeon__grandchild__group {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.accordeon__grandchild__item {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordeon">


  <div class="accordeon__item">

    <div class="accordeon__item__title">
      Строительство домов
    </div>

    <div class="accordeon__child__group">

      <div class="accordeon__child__item">

        <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
          Cтроительство кирпичных домов
        </div>
        <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">

          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст 1</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Так много</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Выпадающих меню</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Куда тебе?</div>

        </div>
        <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->

      </div>
      <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

      <div class="accordeon__child__item">
        <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
          Cтроительство кирпичных домов
        </div>
        <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">

          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст 1</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Так много</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Выпадающих меню</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Куда тебе?</div>


        </div>
        <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->
      </div>
      <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

      <div class="accordeon__child__item">
        <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
          Cтроительство кирпичных домов
        </div>
        <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">

          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст 1</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Так много</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Выпадающих меню</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Куда тебе?</div>

        </div>
        <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->
      </div>
      <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

      <div class="accordeon__child__item">
        <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
          Cтроительство кирпичных домов
        </div>
        <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">

          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст 1</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Так много</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Выпадающих меню</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Куда тебе?</div>

        </div>
        <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->
      </div>
      <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

    </div>
    <!-- .accordeon__child__group -->

  </div>
  <!-- .accordeon__item -->

  <div class="accordeon__item">

    <div class="accordeon__item__title">
      Строительство домов
    </div>

    <div class="accordeon__child__group">

      <div class="accordeon__child__item">

        <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
          Cтроительство кирпичных домов
        </div>
        <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">

          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст 1</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Так много</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Выпадающих меню</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Куда тебе?</div>

        </div>
        <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->

      </div>
      <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

      <div class="accordeon__child__item">
        <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
          Cтроительство кирпичных домов
        </div>
        <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">

          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст 1</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Так много</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Выпадающих меню</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Куда тебе?</div>

        </div>
        <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->
      </div>
      <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

      <div class="accordeon__child__item">
        <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
          Cтроительство кирпичных домов
        </div>
        <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">

          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст 1</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Так много</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Выпадающих меню</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Куда тебе?</div>

        </div>
        <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->
      </div>
      <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

      <div class="accordeon__child__item">
        <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
          Cтроительство кирпичных домов
        </div>
        <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">

          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст1</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Так много</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Выпадающих меню</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Куда тебе?</div>

        </div>
        <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->
      </div>
      <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

    </div>
    <!-- .accordeon__child__group -->

  </div>
  <!-- .accordeon__item -->

  <div class="accordeon__item">

    <div class="accordeon__item__title">
      Строительство домов
    </div>

    <div class="accordeon__child__group">

      <div class="accordeon__child__item">

        <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
          Cтроительство кирпичных домов
        </div>
        <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">

          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст 1</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Так много</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Выпадающих меню</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Куда тебе?</div>

        </div>
        <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->

      </div>
      <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

      <div class="accordeon__child__item">
        <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
          Cтроительство кирпичных домов
        </div>
        <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">

          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст 1</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Так много</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Выпадающих меню</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Куда тебе?</div>


        </div>
        <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->
      </div>
      <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

      <div class="accordeon__child__item">
        <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
          Cтроительство кирпичных домов
        </div>
        <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">

          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст 1</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Так много</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Выпадающих меню</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Куда тебе?</div>

        </div>
        <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->
      </div>
      <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

      <div class="accordeon__child__item">
        <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
          Cтроительство кирпичных домов
        </div>
        <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">

          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст 1</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Так много</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Выпадающих меню</div>
          <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Куда тебе?</div>

        </div>
        <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->
      </div>
      <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

    </div>
    <!-- .accordeon__child__group -->

  </div>
  <!-- .accordeon__item -->


</div>
<!-- .accordeon -->
```

Comment: ох, как много для аккордеона...

Comment: `if (j == i) { continue; } item.offsetParent.classList.remove('active');` — в этой строчке оно всегда убирается, поэтому проверка `if (!item.offsetParent.classList.contains('active'))` — всегда возвращает true. Убрать из кода тот `item.offsetParent.classList.remove('active');` — заработает. P.s. Очевидно вы знаете, как убирать класс. Но код такой, что сами запутались, поэтому вопрос скорее должен был быть про стиль кода в целом)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я при клике, по задумке, убирал у всех элементов классы `active`, кроме того, на которого кликнули. Но я неправильно выбрал, как убирать у всех элементов классы.
У меня было так, я убирал класс у того же родительского элемента несколько раз:

```js
item.offsetParent.classList.remove('active');
```

А надо было проходиться по item'ам

```js
accordeon__item[j].classList.remove('active');
```

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {


let accordeon = document.querySelector('.accordeon');
let accordeon__item = accordeon.querySelectorAll('.accordeon__item');
let accordeon__item__title = accordeon.querySelectorAll('.accordeon__item__title');
let accordeon__child__item = accordeon.querySelectorAll('.accordeon__child__item');
let accordeon__child__item__title = accordeon.querySelectorAll('.accordeon__child__item__title');
let accordeon__child__group = accordeon.querySelectorAll('.accordeon__child__group');
let accordeon__grandchild__group = accordeon.querySelectorAll('.accordeon__grandchild__group');

accordeon__child__item__title.forEach((item, i, array) => {
 item.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  if (!item.offsetParent.offsetParent.offsetParent.classList.contains('active')) {
   return;
  }
  item.offsetParent.classList.add('active');
 });

 accordeon__grandchild__group[i].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  item.offsetParent.classList.add('active');
 });

 item.offsetParent.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  item.offsetParent.classList.remove('active');
 });
});

accordeon__item__title.forEach((item, i, array) => {

 let height = accordeon__child__group[i].offsetHeight;
 accordeon__child__group[i].style.height = 0 + 'px';
 item.addEventListener('click', () => { // Клик по меню

  for (let j = 0; j < accordeon__item.length; j++) {
   accordeon__item[j].style.transition = 'height 0.3s linear, opacity 0.05s linear';
   accordeon__child__group[j].style.height = 0 + 'px';
   accordeon__child__group[j].style.opacity = '0';
   if (j == i) {
    continue;
   }
   accordeon__item[j].classList.remove('active');
  } // Обнуляю все элемы по высоте и прозрачности

  for (let j = 0; j < accordeon__child__item.length; j++) {
   accordeon__child__item[j].style.cursor = 'default';
  } // обнуляю все курсоры

  if (item.offsetParent.classList.contains('active')) {
   item.offsetParent.style.transition = 'height 0.3s linear, opacity 0.05s linear';
   accordeon__child__group[i].style.height = 0 + 'px';
   accordeon__child__group[i].style.opacity = '0';
   item.offsetParent.classList.remove('active');
  } else {
   item.offsetParent.style.transition = 'height 0.3s linear, opacity 0.3s linear';
   accordeon__child__group[i].style.height = height + 'px';
   accordeon__child__group[i].style.opacity = '1';
   item.offsetParent.classList.add('active');
  }



  for (let j = 0; j < item.nextElementSibling.children.length; j++) {

   if (item.offsetParent.classList.contains('active')) {
    // при клике все элементам .accordeon__child__item задаётся cursor pointer или
    // default, в зависимости от наличия класса active у .accordeon__item
    item.nextElementSibling.children[j].style.cursor = 'pointer';
   } else {
    item.nextElementSibling.children[j].style.cursor = 'default';
   }

  }

 }); // Клик по меню

});

});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Open+Sans:400,600,700|Raleway:400,900&display=swap');

/* 
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 */

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.accordeon {
 max-width: 250px;
 color: white;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.accordeon__item {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform .5s linear;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.accordeon__item__title {
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #3b7ba7;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.accordeon__item:not(:last-child) {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.accordeon__child__group {
 position: relative;
 transition: height .3s linear,
    opacity .3s linear;
 opacity: 0;
}

.accordeon__child__item {
 position: relative;
}

.accordeon__child__item__title {
 padding: 5px 10px;
 background-color: #b1cfe3;
 transition: background-color .2s linear;
}

.accordeon__child__item.active .accordeon__child__item__title {
 background-color: #7fb5d8;
}

.accordeon__grandchild__group {
 background-color: orange;
 position: absolute;
 left: 100%;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 transform-origin: top left;
 transform: scaleX(0);
 transition: transform .2s linear;
}

.accordeon__child__item.active .accordeon__grandchild__group{
 transform: scaleX(1);
}

.accordeon__grandchild__item {
 padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordeon">


 <div class="accordeon__item">

        <div class="accordeon__item__title">
         Строительство домов
        </div>

        <div class="accordeon__child__group">

         <div class="accordeon__child__item">

          <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
           Cтроительство кирпичных домов
          </div>
             <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">
              
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст1</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст3</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст4</div>

             </div> <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->

         </div> <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

   <div class="accordeon__child__item">
          <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
           Cтроительство кирпичных домов
          </div>
             <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">
              
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст1</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст3</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст4</div>

             </div> <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->
         </div> <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

         <div class="accordeon__child__item">
          <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
           Cтроительство кирпичных домов
          </div>
             <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">
              
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст1</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст3</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст4</div>

             </div> <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->
         </div> <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

         <div class="accordeon__child__item">
          <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
           Cтроительство кирпичных домов
          </div>
             <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">
              
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст1</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст3</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст4</div>

             </div> <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->
         </div> <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

        </div> <!-- .accordeon__child__group -->

 </div> <!-- .accordeon__item -->

 <div class="accordeon__item">

        <div class="accordeon__item__title">
         Строительство домов
        </div>

        <div class="accordeon__child__group">

         <div class="accordeon__child__item">

          <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
           Cтроительство кирпичных домов
          </div>
             <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">
              
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст1</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст3</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст4</div>

             </div> <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->

         </div> <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

   <div class="accordeon__child__item">
          <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
           Cтроительство кирпичных домов
          </div>
             <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">
              
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст1</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст3</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст4</div>

             </div> <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->
         </div> <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

         <div class="accordeon__child__item">
          <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
           Cтроительство кирпичных домов
          </div>
             <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">
              
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст1</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст3</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст4</div>

             </div> <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->
         </div> <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

         <div class="accordeon__child__item">
          <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
           Cтроительство кирпичных домов
          </div>
             <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">
              
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст1</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст3</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст4</div>

             </div> <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->
         </div> <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

        </div> <!-- .accordeon__child__group -->

 </div> <!-- .accordeon__item -->

 <div class="accordeon__item">

        <div class="accordeon__item__title">
         Строительство домов
        </div>

        <div class="accordeon__child__group">

         <div class="accordeon__child__item">

          <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
           Cтроительство кирпичных домов
          </div>
             <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">
              
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст1</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст3</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст4</div>

             </div> <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->

         </div> <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

   <div class="accordeon__child__item">
          <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
           Cтроительство кирпичных домов
          </div>
             <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">
              
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст1</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст3</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст4</div>

             </div> <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->
         </div> <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

         <div class="accordeon__child__item">
          <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
           Cтроительство кирпичных домов
          </div>
             <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">
              
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст1</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст3</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст4</div>

             </div> <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->
         </div> <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

         <div class="accordeon__child__item">
          <div class="accordeon__child__item__title">
           Cтроительство кирпичных домов
          </div>
             <div class="accordeon__grandchild__group">
              
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст1</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст2</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст3</div>
     <div class="accordeon__grandchild__item">Текст4</div>

             </div> <!-- .accordeon__grandchild__group -->
         </div> <!-- .accordeon__child__item -->

        </div> <!-- .accordeon__child__group -->

 </div> <!-- .accordeon__item -->

 
        
</div> <!-- .accordeon -->
```